# I can't activate my iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, ios, activation-lock

My iPhone 4S is suddenly locked and it asks for Apple ID and Password. When I added them, it says my Apple ID can't activate my phone.

I can't see my iPhone listed on Find My Phone page on iCloud.com. But on my phone it is bound to that Apple ID.

Are there other ways to activate?